# Firebase order by child not returning any data

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to validate users to login into my application using Firebase authentication that email and password. When I query the database for the user identification (ID) I do not get any data:

```
 DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
    Query uid = ref.orderByChild("uid");
    String TAG = "Datauid";
    Log.d(TAG, "checkUserAccessLevel:"+uid);
    ref.orderByChild("uid").equalTo(firebaseAuth.getUid())
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                  for (DataSnapshot ds: snapshot.getChildren()){
                      String accounttype = ""+ds.child("isUser").getValue();
                      if (accounttype.equals("1")){
                          progressDialog.dismiss();

                          startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, DashBoard.class));
                          finish();
                      }
```

when I debug I get the following lines

```
D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about user ( 
DOoGTMWzUmfmOLuCxU50Z8p1Xaw2 ).
I/System.out: [socket]:check permission begin!
D/Datauid: checkUserAccessLevel:com.google.firebase.database.Query@d7af6ee
```

firebase json file

```
"Users" : {
"5MilHXe1EjcJikuebSm9iYuazyq2" : {
  " isUser" : "1",
  " latitude" : "0.0",
  " name" : "Florence Kioko",
  " online" : "true",
  "address " : "",
  "country " : "",
  "county " : "",
  "email " : "florencekioko389@gmail.com",
  "longitude " : "0.0",
  "phone " : "0711473228",
  "profileImage " : "",
  "timestamp " : "1605815768235",
  "town " : "",
  "uid " : "5MilHXe1EjcJikuebSm9iYuazyq2"
},
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Comment: @AlexMamo JSON sample is added.

Comment: I would like to propose that there's no reason to do what you're doing to start with. You're performing a query on a /users node when you already know the exact path to that node - and you can just read the node directly by the users uid at */users/5MilHXe1EjcJikuebSm9iYuazyq2*. Maybe there's more to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code lies in the fact that the name of the property in your database is different than the one you are using in the following line of code:

```
String accounttype = ""+ds.child("isUser").getValue();
```

In the database you have:

```
" isUser" : "1"
```

Containing whitespace while in the above line of code is without that whitespace. To solve this, simply add the whitespace in front:

```
String accounttype = ""+ds.child(" isUser").getValue();
```

However, it will be more convenient to get rid of those whitespaces in the database and use the calls to `.child("isUser")` as you have now.